# known the attribute of a class how to get the class in python

Tags: python

```
class person:    
    def __init__(self, name, gender):
        self.name=name
        self.gender=gender

b=person('bob','male')
b.name='bob'
b.gender='male'
```

Now I have a string 'bob', how can I get the object b?

Thanks a lot for all the answers and help. Let me be more clearer. If I assume there can only be unique names and my goal is to find bob's gender (I only know 'bob' but I do not know b). Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Your purpose?  This probably isn't the easiest way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: You could create a `PersonFinder` class? Need more info

Comment: If you just want to be able to retrieve an object given a string, you can always just use a dictionary to map the string to the object.

Comment: Do you want to find all objects in your program that use the string `'bob'` or just `person` objects that use that string? Can there be multiple `person` objects using `bob`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers and help. Let me be more clearer. If I assume there can only be unique names and my goal is to find bob's gender (I only know 'bob' but I do not know b). Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

You can't, because - just like in the real world - there can be multiple `people` with the name 'bob'.

Comment: even before edit, the example only had one person named bob, so this is not really an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you have some way of knowing who all of your people are. Let's say you have a list of people, and you want to find 'bob'.

```
a = person('anne', 'female')
b = person('bob', 'male')
c = person('cathy', 'female')

people = [a, b, c]
```

Now you can check each person to see if their name is 'bob'.

```
maybe_bob = [pers for pers in people if pers.name == 'bob']
```

If 'bob' exists, we can access his object by calling the first item in the list.

```
try:
    bob = maybe_bob[0]
except IndexError:
    print "No one named 'bob'."
```

Of course, like wim said, this will break down if there are multiple people named 'bob' in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Since bob is unique you can get the instance with ast and pull the gender from that:

```
import inspect
import importlib
import ast   

class FindAttr(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.b = None

    def visit_Assign(self, node):
        for t in node.targets:
            if isinstance(t, ast.Attribute) and hasattr(node.value, "s"):
                if node.value.s == self.name:
                    self.b = (getattr(mod,t.value.id))
                    return


mod = "test"
mod = importlib.import_module(mod)
p = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(mod))

f = FindAttr("bob")
f.visit(p)
```

using your example in test.py:

```
In [4]: mod = "test"

In [5]: mod = importlib.import_module(mod)

In [6]: p = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(mod))

In [7]: f = FindAttr("bob")

In [8]: f.visit(p)


In [9]: print(f.b)
<test.person instance at 0x7f2a78e623f8>
In [10]: print(f.b.gender)
male

In [11]: print(f.b.name)
bob
In [12]: print(f.b.__class__)
test.person
```

Answer (score 0):

having a `dict` for reverse lookup of objects is probably what you want:

```
class person:   
    people_database = {} 
    def __init__(self, name, gender):
        person.people_database[name] = self 
                  #add this instance to the database
                  #possibly overriding the previous entry with this name
        self.name=name
        self.gender=gender

b=person('bob','male')

print (person.people_database["bob"])
print (b)
print(b is person.people_database["bob"])
```

although do know that if you change the name of a person like:

```
b=person('bob','male')
b.name = "susan"
```

this technique will obviously not work properly.